# Sharing a block device as a file through CIFS

Tags: linux, samba, block-device, cifs

Is it possible to share a block device through CIFS on Linux? If yes, how?

I.e. I have two computers, Linux on box A, and Windows on box B. I have a hard disk connected to box A, it's name is `/dev/sdx`. I would like to share this block device as a file inside a Samba share, so that Windows (or any other OS) on box B will be able to read it as a normal file.